# Can the Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack be installed via 7 docker containers?

Tags: cloud, openstack, landscape, docker, openstack-autopilot

The Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack directions state the following (see [Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)):

> Installing Ubuntu OpenStack requires at least seven machines with two disks, two of which have two network interfaces (NICs).

Instead of using seven machines, has anyone done this with seven docker containers?  If so, does anyone already have the docker files to do this? !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you build an OpenStack cloud in Docker containers using the OpenStack Autopilot? No.

There are multiple ways you can build and deploy OpenStack on Ubuntu:

1. (easiest) use the OpenStack Autopilot. As you noticed, currently this requires 7 machines.
2. Juju.  You can use Juju to deploy and configure OpenStack services. You need to install MAAS and Juju, but you do not need to know about OpenStack as much.
3. (hardest) Apt. follow the installation guide for Ubuntu on OpenStack.org, and build your configuration manually. You will need to learn quite a bit about OpenStack.

All three solutions require hardware, because OpenStack is infrastructure, and while it can be faked to test patches, OpenStack with almost no hardware is... hardly useful.

If you want to test OpenStack in the small scale, not for production, I recommend for now you use:

```
apt-get install openstack
```

and try the single system cloud configuration you can build there. In alternative, you can try DevStack, which also gives you a (hardly realistic) cloud packed into one box.

Finally, I hear the next beta of the OpenStack Autopilot may require fewer hardware resources for non-HA configurations. You may want to wait a few weeks until that's out and see if we managed to bring the bar low enough for you - you will still need a few machines, but not 7.